# How to subtract end time and start time in dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I am trying to subtract End_time and start_time to find the duration.
Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
df['start_time'] = 01-04-2020 03:29:35
df['end_time'] = 01-04-2020 03:29:50
```

desired output:

```
df['duration'] = 00:00:15
```

Comment: Use `df['duration'] = df['end_time'] - df['start_time']`

Comment: @jezrael i am getting error - unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Convert borh columns to datetimes before subtracting

Comment: @jezrael can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: `df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']) - pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])`

Comment: @jezrael in output- ' 0 days 00:00:11'. days is also coming.

Comment: @jezrael how to get time only in output.

Comment: added new dupe for convert timedeltas to strings